# Python manage.py startapp does not work

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-rest-framework

When I run the python manage.py startapp "app name" command in my Django project directory nothing happens... Every other manage.py command works without problem.
What could be the problem? 
Thanks a lot!! 
Andrew

Comment: Do you get any error message? Which django version are you using?

Comment: Do you have a space in "app name"..?

Answer (score 3):

The first line in manage.py breaks the file on windows. The first line should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Removing it fixes the issue for me. Please try this is really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs due to Python Path is not set, you can reinstall python and check the box that says "Add to Path 3.9"

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the correct version of Python and correct version of Django?

To check Django:
python manage.py --version

Make sure you are running the right versions, if you are have Python 3 and Python 2 installed you may have multiple versions of Django.

Comment: I only have python 3 on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set environment variables on the command line?  This path is if you were using vagrant.

PYTHONPATH=/vagrant/www DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings django-admin.py startapp

Then try manage.py does it work? Without setting envs on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a virtual environment is necessary to get the above command working. In the virtual environment you can specifically install Django and it is done so as to ensure that no other package interfers with the Django framework. I was also facing the same issue but after creating a virtual environment, things became super easy!!!
I would recommend using pycharm as creating a virtual environment is just as easy as running a hello world program!!. Also paste the following code at the settings.py script at the end   :
                                       ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']
Also specify the correct directory while running in the terminal. Be sure to check that the code should be written inside the project directory.
Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue and saw this question. Tried the methods mentioned by some of the users but it did not work. Surprisingly the only thing I had to do was remove the word "python" from the command. All I typed in the command line was - manage.py startapp "appname"

I have no idea what difference does it make or how I made it work, but if anyone has a similar problem I hope your issue gets resolved.

I think it maybe because i had previously added the directory I am working in the PATH variable. Not sure. Someone has an opinion on this, do share.

Answer (score 0):

I think i may have found the solution. If you're running on python 3.7 or above, try setting your directory to `~\YourProjectName\YourProjectName` with the cd commmand then type `py -m django startapp <appName>`

Answer (score 0):

The command
$ python-admin startapp main
returns the error " bash: python-admin: command not found".
I was able to resolve using the following command instead
$ py -m django startapp main

Answer (score 0):

if some of you are following old tutorials on django then after you have python version 3.7 or above then the command "python manage.py startapp 'appname'" doesnt works.//well it didn't work for me so insted of that command you can use "py -m django startapp 'appname'"
it worked for me so you can also try that..

Answer (score 0):

I solved by changing the directory name to ~\YourProjectName\YourProjectName.
Before i was having different names on the project names. then type python manage.py startapp

Answer (score -2):

the command -> manage.py startapp 'appname'" works for python version upto 3.7 and for 3.7 and above version used command -> "py -m django startapp 'appname'" it works for me...

Comment: There isn't any different between these commands.